# excel filter data with many headers

Tags: excel, filter, grouping

I have a really long excel spreadsheet which I need to sort in a really unusual way:

I have many columns, one of which is full of numbers and blank spaces. The column is cut into many parts and is separated by blank spaces. The blank spaces act as the beginning and the end of two areas.

What I need to do is to leave only the numbers that are bigger than 999999999 and smaller than 2000000000 while keeping only the blank spaces adjacent to them. (and filtering all other columns the same way this one column is filtered)

--- Example Table:

```
Name  | ID.................  | other data
Bob.. |......................|~-~-~---~-``~
Taxes |  1000077008          | ~~ -`~ `~ ~--
Alice |......................| ~~--~-~ ~_~
Carel |......................|~~ ~ ~--_ ~~
Beans | 2000007804           |  ~ ~_~ `~ ~~ `
Coffee| 1000078363           | ~ ~-`--`-` `_~-
```

--- Example Filtered Table:

```
Name  | ID.................  | other data
Bob.. |......................|~-~-~---~-``~
Taxes |  1000077008          | ~~ -`~ `~ ~--
Carel.|......................|~~ ~ ~--_ ~~
Coffee| 1000078363           | ~ ~-`--`-` `_~-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spaces in front of the numbers show that the format is Text. Change the format in Excel to `General` or to `Numeric` and use a custom filter to achieve what you want.

This is an example of a custom filter:
[image]

If you cannot change the format, then use the `=INT(TRIM(A1))` formula in Excel and sort them.

Comment: 1. Stackoverflow added the spaces by itself
2. What is that custom filter exactly? Where do I find it and what do I set it to?

Comment: Yes, but doing this for 1000000000 numbers is gonna be hard, and if I firstly make an if function in a separate column and then filter that, all the empty separators (like Alice in the example spreadsheet) still remain and cannot be removed.

Comment: @umnikos - for the empty values, you may use =IF(ISBLANK()) and eliminate them as well. And why should you do it for 1000~ numbers? You should do it just once?

Comment: I need to leave only SOME blank numbers man! Wait, what if I check if it's blank aaand if the cell below it is a number... maybe that will work, lemme check

Comment: I think =IF(OR(AND(F18=""; NOT(F19="")); AND(F18>999999999; F18<2000000000));TRUE;FALSE) is as best as it can get. Still does the job, marking your post as a solution.

Comment: @umnikos - glad I could help you achieve what you wanted